# Excel test file double columns

Tags: excel, jrules, ilog-elixir

[image]I am trying to test my rule project in eclipse using IBM Ilog but although there are no problem when checking the project before generating test file. For some reason my excel test template for scenarios is generated with double columsn for each object.
Example I have a class Claim which has periodstart etc.. when excel is generated there are two columns to fill for a scenario with the heading periodstart. One bold the other not.

[image]

Comment: Please share the code of your class Claim

Comment: It just an assignment. We didn't really understand the double columns but sometimes when BOM was being generated they were doubled in the excel file sometimes not. We sticked to using one of this non doubled columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code of your class Claim perhaps you have the attribute visibilty public

> public String periodStart;

and in addition

> public void setPeriodStart(String periodStart){ //... }

-->make the attribute private or remove the setter method

Comment: I added a printscreen of the class code. It seems to be a inconsistency sometimes app some times not. Can't figure out why..

Comment: Try to respect the java naming convention: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

private String periodStart;